# Using Ruby Variable in Script Tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm defining an intercom event in my rails controller like so:

**object_controller.rb**

```
@object.save
@intercom_event = 'object-saved'
```

In a partial that exists in my `application.html.erb` I am trying to run this script:

```
<script>
  Intercom('trackEvent', '<%= @intercom_event %>');
</script>
```

The script runs and sends the event up to Intercom like its supposed to. I thought I am placing the ruby variable into the `<script>` tag correctly except the output for `@intercom_event` is: `<%= @intercom_event %>` when it should be: `object-saved`.

Additionally if I were to wrap this `<script>` tag in an if statement (so that it doesn't send an event every time the page is reloaded) like so:

```
<% if @intercom_event.present? %>
  <script>
    Intercom('trackEvent', '<%= @intercom_event %>');
  </script>
<% end %>
```

It ignores the script altogether, even when `@intercom_event` is defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it to work by looking to see if the params is present instead of the `@intercom_event` variable

```
<% if params[:intercom].present? %>
  <script>
    Intercom('trackEvent', '<%= params[:intercom] %>');
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track:

```
<%- if @intercom_event.present? -%>
  <%= javscript_tag do -%>
    Intercom('trackEvent', '<%=j @intercom_event %>');
  <%- end -%>
<%- end -%>
```

The `j` method escapes for JavaScript context like the companion method `h` escapes for HTML. This is important to avoid scripting errors.

For more complicated structures, `@intercom_event.to_json` would give you a JavaScript compatible representation.

Comment: Hmm still not sending when wrapped in a `<%- if @intercom_event.present? -%>` tag. When I removed the if statement it's now sending nothing up to intercom. I wonder why the variable defined in the controller isn't being seen in the view file

Comment: Controller instance variables are automatically propagated down to the view level. Are you sure you're hitting the right action? Always check `log/development.log`.